# Finding a function with properties

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, roots

I am looking for a function $f(x)$ with the following properties:

1. Positive for $x\in(-\infty, 0)$ but tangent to the x-axis at $x=-1$
2. A root at $x=0$ and negative for $x\in(0, 2)$
3. A root at $x=2$ and positive for $x\in(2, \infty)$

I thought $f(x)=x(x-2)(x+1)^2$ would do the trick but it does not. The graph I have drawn on paper has a "w" shape with a local minimum at $x=-1$, a local maximum between $x=-1$ and $x=0$ and a local minimum between $x=0$ and $x=2$.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If the graph is tangent to the $x$-axis at $x=-1$, the function will have a root there (and so $f(-1)$ cannot be positive).

Comment: You mean the derivative will have a root there.

Comment: @FooBarrigno The function will as well, if I'm interpreting "tangent" correctly (the two curves $y=f(x)$ and $y=0$ are tangent to each other at $x=-1$). Perhaps the OP meant "the line tangent to the graph of $f$ at $x=-1$ is parallel to the $x$-axis".

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, my interpretation wasn't accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that [your function works](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%7Bx%28x%E2%88%922%29%28x%2b1%29%5E2%7D%20from%20-1.5%20to%202.25):

[image]

Comment: You are right! I just needed to zoom in further on Maple to verify. Even with both Axes going from -10 to 10 it just looked like a giant U (parabola)

Answer (score 2):

It *does* do the trick (well done). You have misdrawn the graph, unfortunately.